# getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner does not return value

Tags: spl-token, token-account

I'm using `getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner` to get token account of wallets. But the function does not return value for some wallets (despite the fact that the wallet contains that token).

This is the code I'm using:

```
    const tokensAccounts = await connection.getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner(walletPublickey, {
      mint,
    });
```

Network: mainnet-beta

Mint: HovGjrBGTfna4dvg6exkMxXuexB3tUfEZKcut8AWowXj

Wallet: CTLGjqVpaZSiLthLQfRHgSiKfTfwovg49EGRcMpSguzF

Thanks!

Comment: Did you make sure your connection is connected to the correct network (e.g. mainnet)?

Comment: @ElliotSolskjaer yes I'm 100% sure, I do log the connection object. The same code gives correct result on other wallet addresses